# Filling a data table using vectorized functions in R

Tags: r, data.table, vectorization

I am trying to fill in a data table in R using vectorized operations:

```
library(data.table)
x = 5
y = 3
Foo = data.table(Bar = 1:x)
Foo[,paste0("simulation",1:y) := Bar * rnorm(y,,Bar)]
```

I would think that for each row, rnorm(y,,Bar) would make a y length vector (using that row's Bar as the standard deviation), multiply that by the Bar value for that row, and fill in the appropriate columns. However, is seems (from other experimentation) to be trying to go down columns first. Is there a way to change this behavior?

Comment: Don't put vectors on table rows, since R stores vectors on columns. Instead just store it in long form: `Foo[, .(Bar = rep(Bar, each = y), v = rnorm(y*.N, , rep(Bar, each=.N)))]` or `Foo[, rnorm(y,,Bar), by=Bar]`

Comment: So you're suggesting only using two columns, and making y rows for each value of Bar? Is there an easy way to collapse that back into the format I want (y+1 columns, only one row for each value of Bar)?

Comment: Yes, you can use `res <- Foo[, rnorm(y,,Bar), by=Bar]; dcast(res, Bar ~ rowid(Bar, prefix="sim"))`. However, I think this is a lot tougher to do analysis with, compared to the more idiomatic `res[, do_stuff, by=Bar]`. Putting it in wide format is most useful for browsing rather than analysis in my experience.

Comment: The thing is, in my actual code I have no guarantee that the Bars are going to be unique (in fact they likely wont; I'm trying to do Monte-Carlo simulations on time series data). This whole system will break in that case, won't it? I guess I could add an index column and group by that?

Comment: Yeah, I would do what you're describing: `simDT = data.table(sid = 1:5, Bar = 1:5); n = 3; s = 5; res = simDT[, .(sid = rep(sid, each=n), v = rnorm(.N*n, , rep(s, each=n)))]`

Comment: cool thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

We can loop through the values of 'Bar' and create the `rnorm`

```
Foo[, paste0("simulation",seq_len(y)) :=transpose(lapply(Bar, function(z) rnorm(y, sd = z)))]
```

Comment: Doesn't this sacrifice the advantages of vectorizing?